# Refresh ArrayList to show new Data into RecyclerView using Click on Spinner Item

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, spinner

Clicking on `Spinner` Item adding new data into `RecyclerView` without removing old ones.

Like, I have `two` Items in a **Spinner** : `Appliances` and `Accessories`.

By default, I am showing `Appliances` data into **RecyclerView**, but whenever I do `tap` on **Accessories** - It is showing `Accessories data` into *RecyclerView*, but `below Appliances data`, whereas I was **expecting** only `Accessories` data into RecyclerView

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    .....

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_screen);
        .........

        stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        stringList.add("Appliances");
        stringList.add("Accessories");

        ArrayAdapter<String> stringArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                stringList);

        spinnerMenu.setAdapter(stringArrayAdapter);

        ......

        initializeAdapter();

        .....

        spinnerMenu.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:                            

                        presenter.loadAppliances();

                        break;

                    case 1:

                        presenter.loadAccessories();

                        break;
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        .......
    }

    public void initializeAdapter() {

        categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Category>());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
    }

    public void addMenu(List<Category> posts) {
        categoryAdapter.addAllData(posts);
        categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

**CategoryAdapter.java:**

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    public void setPosts(List<Categories> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public void clearData() {
        posts.clear();
    }

    public void addAllData(List<Categories> posts) {
        this.posts.addAll(posts);
    }

}
```

Comment: why It has been downvoted ? I don't think here is something wrong I posted.

Comment: hey clear your list before calling  `menuPresenter.loadAppliances();` and after call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: tried but getting null pointer exception

Comment: Better to post it logcat

Comment: Please show the code for `menuPresenter.loadXXX`

Comment: can somebody pls help me with a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411583/recyclerview-with-checkbox-checks-all-items-in-subcategories-of-same-index-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First clear your old ArrayList and than add data into Arraylist.

```
 public void addMenu(List<Category> posts) {
    categoryAdapter.addAllData(posts);
    categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addAllData(List<Categories> posts) {
    this.posts.clear();
    this.posts.addAll(posts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the adapter when an item is selected. So try this:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       initializeAdapter();
       //after this the switch case
```

I would also recommend that you have a way to know the spinner Menu Position. 
After the first `menupresenter.loadAppliances();` have `int positionSelected = 0;`

then in the switch case,

```
switch position
   case: 0
     if(positionSelected != 0) {
         initializeAdapter();
         menupresenter.loadAppliances();
         positionSelected = 0;
     }...

   case: 1
     if(positionSelected != 1) {
         initializeAdapter();
         menupresenter.loadAccessories();
         positionSelected = 1;
     }...
```

This will ensure that you don't reset the recyclerView adapter unnecessarily. Like if appliaces data is being shown and the user, selects appliances again in the dropdown