# RecyclerView with checkbox checks all items in subcategories of same index value

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview which lists a number of items and clicking on1 item opens a dialog with subcategories of that item.Each subcategory has a checkbpx with it.The problem is that when I click on 1 checkbox and click OK and go back to select another category the item of the same index in another subcategory is also checked.this is my code from the Dialog box which lists the subcategories

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.bt_ok:
          //  Updatecatagory();
            for (int i = 0; i < mysubcatagoryAdapter.catagory_list.size(); i++) {

                if (!mysubcatagoryAdapter.isChecked) {
                   // mysubcatagoryAdapter.removehash.get(i).;
                    //mysubcatagoryAdapter.removehash.clear();
                    mysubcatagoryAdapter.removehash.remove(i);
                }
            }

            finish();
    }
}
```

this is my adapter

```
public class CustomRecycleViewAdapter_Language extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecycleViewAdapter_Language.MyLanguageViewHolder> 
{
private Context context;
public ArrayList<String> catagory_list;
private View resourceLayout;
private OnSelected onSelected;
private String checkForAction;
public ArrayList<String> removehash;
public boolean isChecked=false;
int count = 1;
SharedPreferences selection = 
getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyLang", MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = selection.edit();

public CustomRecycleViewAdapter_Language(Context context, ArrayList<String> 
catagory_list, String checkForAction) {
    this.context = context;
    this.catagory_list = catagory_list;
    this.checkForAction = checkForAction;

}

public class MyLanguageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView tv_option;
    private CheckBox cb_option;
    private RelativeLayout rl_option;

    public MyLanguageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_option = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_option);
        cb_option = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cb_option);
        rl_option = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_option);
    }
}

@Override
public MyLanguageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    resourceLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.resource_selectfilter, null);
    MyLanguageViewHolder mcv = new MyLanguageViewHolder(resourceLayout);
    return mcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyLanguageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     holder.tv_option.setText(catagory_list.get(position).split("#")
    [1].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + 
    catagory_list.get(position).split("#")[1].substring(1));
    removehash = new ArrayList<>();
    removehash.clear();

    Common.languageselection.add(position);

    for (int i = 0; i < catagory_list.size(); i++) {

        removehash.add(catagory_list.get(i).split("#")[0]);
    }


    if (!Common.isFlag) {


        try {
            if(Common.languageselection.size()!=0) {

                if 
           (Common.setid.get(position).equals(String.valueOf(position))) {

                    holder.cb_option.setChecked(true);


                }
            }
            count = 2;
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }


    }


    if (checkForAction.equals("UPLOAD")) {
        holder.cb_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }


    holder.rl_option.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (onSelected != null) {

                if (count == 2) {
                    if (!holder.cb_option.isChecked()) {
                        holder.cb_option.setChecked(true);
                        removehash.get(position);
                        isChecked=true;
                        Common.setid.add(String.valueOf(position));
                    } else if (holder.cb_option.isChecked()) {

                        holder.cb_option.setChecked(false);
                        Common.setid.remove(String.valueOf(position));
                        removehash.remove(position);


                    }

                    onSelected.onClicked(view, removehash.get(position));
                    isChecked=true;

                } else {

                    if (!holder.cb_option.isChecked()) {
                        holder.cb_option.setChecked(true);
                        Common.setid.add(String.valueOf(position));
                        removehash.get(position);
                        isChecked=true;

                    } else if (holder.cb_option.isChecked()) {
                        holder.cb_option.setChecked(false);
                        removehash.remove(position);
                        Common.setid.remove(String.valueOf(position));
                    }
                    if (checkForAction.equals("UPLOAD")) {
                        holder.cb_option.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        onSelected.onClicked(view, catagory_list.get(position));
                    } else
                        onSelected.onClicked(view, removehash.get(position));
                    Common.holdvalues.add(removehash.get(position));

                }


                Log.v("SHOW", removehash.toString());


            }
        }
    });


  //        try
  //        {
  //
  //            if(Common.languageselection.size()>0)
 //            {
//            for(int i=0;i<Common.languageselection.size();i++)
//            {
//
//
//                
            if(Common.languageselection.get(i).equals(Common.setid.get(i)))
//                {
//
//                    holder.cb_option.setChecked(true);
//                }
//                else
//                    holder.cb_option.setChecked(false);
//
//            }
//            }
//
//        }catch (Exception e)
//        {
//
//        }

   /* holder.tv_option.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (onlanguageSelected != null) {
                onlanguageSelected.onLanguageClicked(view,catagory_list.get(position));
            }
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return catagory_list.size();
}

public void setOnSelected(OnSelected onSelected) {
    this.onSelected = onSelected;
}

public interface OnSelected {
    public void onClicked(View view, String selectedVal);
}


}
```

this is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_subcatagories"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
         </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_respondcontainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rv_subcatagories"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt_ok"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:text="OK"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerView Items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingRight="3dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_option"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb_option"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
        android:gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_option"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Arindom"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/filtertextcolor"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/UnderPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_option"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/linecolor" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From your question i made a example pls check if it helps.**

> Main Class RecyclerView Activity

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CategoryClickListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewCategory;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private Context context = RecyclerViewActivity.this;
    private Activity activity = RecyclerViewActivity.this;


        private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;
        private CategoryClickListener categoryClickListener;

        ArrayList<ArrayList<SubcategoryModel>> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

            categoryClickListener = this;
            getDummyData();
            recyclerViewCategory = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
            recyclerViewCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerViewCategory.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, listData, categoryClickListener);
            recyclerViewCategory.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);


        }

        public void getDummyData() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                ArrayList<SubcategoryModel> subCategoryData = new ArrayList<>();
                subCategoryData.add(new SubcategoryModel("Sub category 1", false));
                subCategoryData.add(new SubcategoryModel("Sub category 2", false));
                subCategoryData.add(new SubcategoryModel("Sub category 3", false));
                subCategoryData.add(new SubcategoryModel("Sub category 4", false));
                subCategoryData.add(new SubcategoryModel("Sub category 5", false));
                listData.add(subCategoryData);
            }
        }
        private void showDialog(ArrayList<SubcategoryModel> listSubcategory) {
            try {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations
                        = R.style.Animation_AppCompat_DropDownUp;

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_subcategory);

                WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
                lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                window.setAttributes(lp);

                RecyclerView recyclerViewSubcategory = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_subcategory);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                recyclerViewSubcategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
                recyclerViewSubcategory.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

                SubCategoryAdapter adapter = new SubCategoryAdapter(context, listSubcategory);
                recyclerViewSubcategory.setAdapter(adapter);


                dialog.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



        @Override
        public void categoryClick(int position) {
               showDialog(listData.get(position));
        }
    }
```

> Category Adapter class

```
public class CategoryAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<SubcategoryModel>> listData;
    private Context context;
    private CategoryClickListener categoryClickListener;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<SubcategoryModel>> listData, CategoryClickListener categoryClickListener) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryClickListener = categoryClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_category_view, parent, false);

        CategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    //This method binds all widgets with a value
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {

            holder.textViewCategory.setText("Category "+(position+1));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != listData ? listData.size() : 0);
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private TextView textViewCategory;


        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            textViewCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCategory);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

               categoryClickListener.categoryClick(getAdapterPosition());


        }
    }
}
```

> Subcategory Adapter class

```
class SubCategoryAdapter   extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubCategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SubcategoryModel> listData;
    private Context context;

    public SubCategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SubcategoryModel> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public SubCategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_subcategory_view, parent, false);

        SubCategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new SubCategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    //This method binds all widgets with a value
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SubCategoryAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {

            SubcategoryModel subCategory = listData.get(position);
            holder.textViewSubCategory.setText(subCategory.name);
            if(subCategory.isChecked)
            {
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != listData ? listData.size() : 0);
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textViewSubCategory;
        private CheckBox checkBox;


        public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewSubCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSubCategory);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    listData.get(getAdapterPosition()).isChecked=isChecked;

                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

> Subcategory Model class

```
public class SubcategoryModel {

    String name;
    boolean isChecked;

    public SubcategoryModel(String name, boolean isChecked)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }

}
```

> Category click listener

```
public interface CategoryClickListener {

    public void categoryClick(int position);

}
```

> activity_recycler_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

> dialog_subcategory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_subcategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

> row_category_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

> row_subcategory_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSubCategory"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

**It may be help you.**

Comment: sorry.didnt work.I can give u a hint if u can help me with that.If I use mysubcatagoryAdapter.removehash.remove(i) or clear(i)  in the activity it fetches the arraylist in the adapter and clears all checks when OK is pressed but I want that what I have checked should be checked in every subcategory and what I have unchecked should be unchecked,can u help me pls?

Comment: can you send me layout file and example data of arraylist? so i can help you better.

Comment: I have edited the question with the layout file and it fetches arraylist data of subcategories with checkbox in each row –

Comment: any news for me?

Comment: I had fixed it somehow but this is a much better answer.it worked.Thanks Chetan.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the listener to null before assigning the checked state in `onBindViewHolder`

```
holder.rl_option.setOnClickListener(null)
```

I created an example using check box listener [here](https://lev-sharone.medium.com/implement-android-recyclerview-list-of-checkboxes-with-select-all-option-double-tier-77acc4b4d41)